# Illustrator: create four double sided arrows to form a circle

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes, path

I'm a little bit newbie to Illustrator, so sorry if my question is pretty banal.

Following art work is what I'd like to design:

[image]

This is the plan (that doesn't work!):

1 - Draw an **empty** circle with required stroke. (A ring, namely)

2 - Erase some part of that ring and divide to to four parts.

3 - Add arrow heads to both sides of each part.

My main problem is conversion of a circle to its corresponding ring. [Here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/33792/convert-shape-to-line-with-a-stroke-in-illustrator) is a question, which might be similar to my problem, but it didn't work. I think I should transform the shape (circle) to a path, then it will become a ring and applying steps 2 and 3 would be possible. Even [this video](https://www.google.ca/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&sqi=2&ved=0ahUKEwjSrOSb78_RAhUD7IMKHSGIBtgQtwIIKTAD&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DY5PCxQeF9vo&usg=AFQjCNFVUwxeOqQSof4D7870vi_Dt_J9tQ&sig2=IrKfaGIhQBGteUF657o7mQ&bvm=bv.144224172,d.amc) didn't help too much because I can't modify the tickness of the final ring by `Stroke > Weight`

Could you give me some advice to find the steps?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your original thinking works. Here it is tried.

[image]

Comment: Oh this one is more accurate. Thank you! I am also learning something new. Did you turn your arrow into a brush like I did?

Comment: Amazingly expressive... Much appreciated for your contributed.

Comment: Keeps the correct form of the circle, easy to repeat and remember, and quick to execute. Very nice answer.

Answer (score 9):

[image]

Make your basic shape with arrow headed
Go to the brush tab or Press F5
click on new brush
[image]

Select Pattern Brush and press ok
Name the brush as you wish
In the spacing 25 and Fit options Add space to fit and press ok
Make a circle remove the color and just apply the stroke.

Answer (score 6):

1. Draw your circle and ensure it's selected.
2. Go to Object > Path > Add Anchor Points, and repeat it another 2-4 times (this part, you might need to judge with your own eyes; I did it a total of four times in my example). I get this:

[image: Circle with several additional anchor points.]

3. With the white arrow tool, click the top anchor point and delete it.

[image: Circle with top anchor point deleted.]

4. Repeat step 3 with the right, bottom, and left anchor points, leaving this:

[image: Four strokes in the shape of a circle.]

You can now select each path to add the correct stroke and arrowheads as desired.

Comment: No problem. Having seen user287001's answer, I think it's the better choice in this particular case, but it's always nice to have multiple approaches to things.

Comment: You are considerably right. Under the aegis of you guy's kindness, I've just learnt a lot of things from Illustrator.

Comment: This approach is very useful when I like to have a non-symmetric formation of the arrows with unbalanced coverage of the shape's boundary... Really useful...

Comment: @Roboticist using dashed strokes isntead?

Answer (score 5):

I'm pretty sure there's plenty of other ways to do it but I would take my arrows and turn them into an art brush and then, I'll make a circle and make sure it has no fill and has an outline and use that art brush I just made that way the arrows will follow the outline of the circle.

Here are screenshots on how I did it:

Basically, during the first step, I made 4 arrows all in all.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Make sure you make 4 arrows in the beginning. I initially started with 2 and it didn't quite work.

I hope this helps! Please let me know if it sounds confusing. I will be glad to help you out some more.

Comment: Thanks in advance. Art brush sounds to be a very powerful tool. I need experience that, extensively.

Comment: if you make the bounding box shape a bit bigger (any transparent box) Then it would make this solution perfect no matter the size of the circle. see [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IlumN.png)

Comment: I honestly did not think about that option. I honestly probably never have done any tinkering around the bounding box. I'll give it a try. Thanks!